# Fluctuation using jquery mobile in Ios and android phonegap (while opening pop up screen an closing)

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile.And i am testing on Ios Ipad .But problem is that fluctuation is occurring
while opening the popup screen and closing the pop up screen.Here is my code.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmib9erjwqw3cfk/Procat.zip

Actually On my Index.html i have three buttons .Press (+)button open pop up screen and fill field it.and press ok button .It is showing fluctuation.I don't know why it is occurring?
I am checking on ios phone and on Ipad

Comment: Can u put the a fiddle for ppl to debug ?? I don think uploading the entire source code is a good move.

Comment: actually using the whole source code will detect the problem..

Comment: without that you can't able to detect the problems and you can't say any thing..