# How to search text with from contends having search, next , previous Button in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to search text from page .I found this good link But i ned to modify something
https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin.Actually in this they use only next and previous button which is working properly.But I need to add  one more functionality like that.

1) Add one search Button on click it will highlight the first occurring search text or it say **there is no matches found**.After that it will not do any thing.
2)After selecting the next it will search from second occurring text ,then next ..

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">

        body{
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        #searchDemo{
            width: 600px;
        }

        #searchContent{
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 584px;
        }

        .back a{
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .message {
            font-size: 13px;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        label{
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            font-size: 13px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .searchForm{
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            margin: 15px 0 5px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.textselect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.search.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            //create searcher
            var searcher = $("#searchContent").search({
                searchType: "highlightSelected",
                searchSelector : "p",
                scrollTo : true
            });

            //make sure we find the same text, otherwise clear search postions
            function find(up) {
                var currentText = searcher.getText();

                var text = $("#searchText").val();



                if (text != currentText) {
                    searcher.setText(text);
                  //  alert(getConcurrencesNumber());

                }

                searcher.nextConcurrence(up);
            }

            //bind events
            $("#prev").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                find(true);
            });

            $("#next").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                find(false);
            });
              $("#search").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                find(true);
            });


        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="searchDemo">
    <p class="back"><a href="https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin"> &lt;&lt; Back to project page</a></p>

    <p class="message">To search over content, please fill input field and click "Previous" or "Next".</p>

    <noscript>
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use search plugin.</p>
    </noscript>

    <div class="searchForm">
        <div>
            <label>Search text</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchText" value="sit"/>
            <input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous">
            <input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
             <input type="button" id="search" value="search">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="searchContent">
        <p style="margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
        <p>Nunc molestie fringilla risus, non pulvinar sapien molestie at.</p>
        <p>Ut id eleifend turpis.</p>
        <p>Praesent ac ipsum nec magna gravida convallis.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse sed magna leo, eu tincidunt dui.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse potenti.</p>
        <p>Ut malesuada dictum odio quis egestas.</p>
        <p>Aenean mollis ornare leo, at auctor neque consequat a.</p>
        <p>Morbi in nibh quis nisl aliquet dignissim vel non nulla.</p>
        <p>Sed leo metus, consectetur et commodo sit amet, molestie nec urna.</p>
        <p>Quisque vestibulum dictum odio, vitae vulputate velit sodales sit amet.</p>
        <p>Fusce sit amet diam nunc.</p>
        <p>Nullam semper, nisi id pulvinar eleifend, eros tortor semper mauris, id facilisis mauris justo ut erat.</p>
        <p>Ut dolor nunc, rutrum in imperdiet et, ultrices a turpis.</p>
        <p>Nam convallis luctus est, quis ornare metus semper non.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u make quick fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/SMLpS/

Comment: Here i my code but i am not able to add js sorch file

Comment: https://github.com/nmartynenko/jquery-search-plugin.Here is my plugin

Comment: @Rohit can you make a valid fiddle?

Comment: actually i am not able to make..

Comment: you can download from git..as demo.. add search button.on click it search first occurrence . than next , next...and previous functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Find check if there are any occurrence, if there are then find the first occurrence.

```
if(searcher.getConcurrencesNumber() > 0){
    searcher.findConcurrence(0);
}
```

Comment: but on clicking next it also  show zero occurrence.I think it it start from first..

Comment: can you answer of these question also.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622604/fluctuation-using-jquery-mobile-in-ios-and-android-phonegap-while-opening-pop-u

Comment: this question also..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620635/how-to-add-done-button-in-date-picker-using-jquery-mobile-ipad